# Tell new users to read the tag wiki

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions, new-users, tag-wiki

On the "Ask Question" page, when the keyboard focus is in the entry box for "Tags", on the right hand side we see a box with some information on "How to Tag".

Can we add an item in there to indicate to users that, after selecting a tag, they can hover the mouse over the selected tags (which now appears below the entry box) to read the Tag-Wiki excerpts, to see if they have selected an appropriate tag? I think this will help with the problem of new users applying grossly inappropriate tags because they don't actually understand what a particular tag is for. (This happens a lot on Math, but also a bit on TeX and other sites that I read.)

Comment: I've thought before this would be nice, but when there are five tags selected, does it still make sense to show five tag wikis?

Comment: Well, my proposal is not to show five wikis, but to just tell the users that if they hover their mouse over the tags, they can read the wiki exerpts *before they click submit*. The functionality to show the exerpts is already there (try it yourself)! It is just not very well known to new users.

Comment: Do new users even look at the box on the right hand side? I seriously doubt it.

Comment: I think a better dup target than [the current one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103456/997587) is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/997587).

Answer (score 3):

Good idea! You can just basically add to the notation already there, as in:

> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. *You can hover your mouse over the tags you chose to read the tag's description and see if it is appropriate.*

The words in italics are words that aren't there already, but could possibly be added.

Answer (score 0):

Would it cost too much to display the tag, or an excerpt when choosing a tag?

I mean the number of tag is limited, so we can have predetermined place-holder to put those descriptions right under the tags when asking a question. This should favourite reading of the tag description.

It could be also useful to encourage people to suggest description for tag that do not have one.